# How do I use the "best fit" locale in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization

### My understanding of the problem so far:

I'm reading [this MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation) which says:

> The locales argument, after stripping off all Unicode extensions, is interpreted as a prioritized request from the application. The runtime compares it against the locales it has available and picks the best one available. Two matching algorithms exist: the "lookup" matcher follows the Lookup algorithm specified in BCP 47; the "best fit" matcher lets the runtime provide a locale that's at least, but possibly more, suited for the request than the result of the Lookup algorithm. If the application doesn't provide a locales argument, or the runtime doesn't have a locale that matches the request, then the runtime's default locale is used. The matcher can be selected using a property of the options argument (see below).

When I read this, it appears that I can use "lookup" and "best fit" the same way, sometimes getting different results.

### However

I can do:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('lookup', options).format(date)
```

But not:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('best fit', options).format(date)
```

I'm using a current version of Firefox (65.0.1 64-bit on Ubuntu), and Firefox doesn't have any open bugs on the issue as far as I can tell, but I get a RangeError when I use `'best fit'`.

### Remaining questions:

Am I supposed to be able to give the `'best fit'` as the locale argument, or can I only use it as the `localeMatcher` in the `options` argument? If I can only use `'best fit'` inside `options`, then what should I specify as the `locale`, given that `locale` is required when `options` is present?

Or should I just open a ticket in Bugzilla?

Comment: REF: **Remaining Questions** Did you miss this part? _The locales argument must be either a string holding a BCP 47 language tag, or an array of such language tags. If the locales argument is not provided or is undefined, the runtime's default locale is used._

Comment: this: `new Intl.DateTimeFormat([],{localeMatcher: "best fit"}).format(date)` works perfectly in FF 65.0.1

Comment: @RandyCasburn oh gee thanks. I should have read closer. So I guess "lookup" is a language tag?

Comment: All good. Internationalization is a tough topic.

Comment: no - lookup is just a string that meets the formatting requirements. But is not found, so falls back to default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, a string is passed to the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` so it *appears* to work. But all it does is not recognize the string as a valid locale and then uses the default.

The second example doesn't work because the string is not formatted in accordance with BCP 47.

You've misinterpreted the API documentation. This:

> The locales argument must be either a string holding a BCP 47 language
>   tag, or an array of such language tags. If the locales argument is not
>   provided or is undefined, the runtime's default locale is used.

clearly indicates the first argument should be a string or (array of strings) that is/are a locale identifiers.

Then this:

> The options argument must be an object with properties that vary
>   between constructors and functions.

So your call to the should look like this:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat([],{localeMatcher: "best fit"}).format(date)
```